# Open .NET app from Web Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, clickonce

I just need to be able to open a .NET app (click once) from within an ASP.NET web page, and pass 2 string parameter to the app.

How can I do this? Any example please, with any method to do it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://madskristensen.net/post/URL-parameters-in-ClickOnce-applications.aspx) explains how to retrieve the parameters from the querystring used to call the ClickOnce app. That should help you to figure out **how to compose the URL**, along with its querystring containing the parameters you want to send.

Answer (score 1):

You could associate your application with a file extension and then simple generate a text file with your parameters from the web application with this extension and that would be opened by your client application.

Edit: If your click once application is deployed from a web site you could just link to that url. Depending on the click once settings the app could be started from the client if already installed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to deploy a click once app - so it can be launched from the start menu, and so it can be launched from a URL. Assuming you have set the app up as the URL-started one, just have a link on any ASP.NET page (or could be pure html, doesn't matter) to the click once app's URL. When the user clicks it their browser, IIS, and their local copy of Windows will all do the work to get the app launched.